# Getting error on aws

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have setup my project on aws server .Now I am doing bundle install and I am getting this error.

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160628-9837-1r9tsw1.rb extconf.rb
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... yes
checking for mysql.h... no
checking for mysql/mysql.h... yes
checking for errmsg.h... no
-----
errmsg.h is missing. You may need to 'apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev' or 'yum install mysql-devel', and try again.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.21 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/mysql2-0.3.21/gem_make.out
Using raindrops 0.16.0
Using sass 3.4.22
Using tilt 2.0.5
Using spring 1.7.1
Using sqlite3 1.3.11
Using will_paginate 3.1.0
Using rdoc 4.2.2
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using nokogiri 1.6.8
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using warden 1.2.6
Using mime-types 3.1
Using net-scp 1.2.1
Using binding_of_caller 0.7.2
Using sprockets 3.6.0
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using uglifier 3.0.0
Using httparty 0.13.7
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.21), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.21'` succeeds before bundling.<br/>
```

I did gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.21' OR yum install mysql-devel both did not work for me .Can anyone tell me what can be the possible problem

```
yum install libmysqlclient-dev
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.nbrc.ac.in
 * epel: mirror.wanxp.id
 * extras: mirror.nbrc.ac.in
 * updates: mirror.nbrc.ac.in
No package libmysqlclient-dev available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Comment: could you confirm that you server has mysql installed?

Comment: I have installed using  yum install libmysqlclient-dev and after that i ran bundle install but the error was same

Comment: how to give confirmation that mysql is installed or not?

Comment: I have created a database by logging in mysql command on aws

Comment: Your distribution supports apt-get try `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev libmysqlclient18` instead of yum

Comment: sudo: apt-get: command not found
thats why i use yum command

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `libmysqlclient-dev` package before attempting to install `mysql2` gem. Check MySql section of [this page](http://ryanbigg.com/2014/10/ubuntu-ruby-ruby-install-chruby-and-you//). Even though mysql server is already installed in your machine, you will need this mysql client package.

You can do `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev` or `yum install libmysqlclient-dev` depending on your linux distro. Make sure this is successfully done. Only after that you can install mysql2 gem: `gem install mysql2`

Hope it helps : )

Comment: I have already tried yum install libmysqlclient-dev and gem install mysql2 but both didn't work for me

Comment: did installation of libmysqlclient-dev complete successfully? If not can you please update your question to include the error logs of that attempt?

Comment: i have updated my question when i have install  libmysqlclient-dev

Comment: What is your linux distro on AWS? CentOS?

Comment: the linux distro is CentOS

Comment: Yeah!! That is only causing all the problems! Can you follow the steps for MySql installation here: https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/installing-mysql-server-on-centos/ and check it MySql is properly installed ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115793/discussion-between-harsh-trivedi-and-aniket-shivam-tiwari).

Answer (score 0):

Error in log already suggest solution for issue:

`errmsg.h is missing. You may need to 'apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev' or 'yum install mysql-devel', and try again.`

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev libmysqlclient18
```

Or

```
sudo yum install mysql-devel
```

Depending on your ubuntu distribution.

Comment: i did all the things which you provided but the error is the same'